# How to append a str from a list whose index is unknown

Tags: python

This may not be a clear explanation but I hope it gets the point through.
I'm making a code that tracks the position of the word ' owl ' used in an user given input. 
I have a input that asks the user to enter some text that contains 'owl' , I've then set it to lowercase and split the text. An empty list is created and I enumerated the index from the text along with a conditional statement that if the word 'owl' is in the text it will append it to the empty list. Heres the problem, I do not know what to call the variable to append

I've tried append(index) but what that does is append the whole index not just the index of the word owl's position. I know that this is caused since if there's just one instance of the word owl, the computer will move on to the next step and append the whole index. I just need to know if theres a way to append just the index of the owl so that once the if statement is met, if the word is owl , it will append the position/index of the word

Heres the code

```
text = input (' enter some text ' )

textsplit = text.split

indexlist = []

for index in enumerate(textsplit):

    if 'owl' in textsplit:

        indexlist.append(index)

print(indexlist)
```

Comment: `text.split` is a function, so you have to call it.... `text.split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `list.index(item)` which provides the index of `item` present in the `list`.
From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.index(x[, start[, end]])
>   Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x.

Also you need to call `textsplit=text.split()` which calls the `split` function and assigns the value to `textsplit`

`textsplit=text.split` assigns the function `split` to `textsplit` which is not what you want

Note that below code will work if you have only one `owl` in your string, which means this does not handle duplicates

```
text = input (' enter some text ' )

textsplit = text.split()

indexlist = []
if 'owl' in textsplit:

    #idx is index of owl in textsplit
    idx = textsplit.index('owl')
    indexlist.append(idx)

print(indexlist)
```

The output will look like

```
 enter some text i owl me
[1]
```

If you want to handle duplicates of `owl` in the string, you can do as follows

```
text = input (' enter some text ' )

textsplit = text.split()

indexlist = []

#Iterate on the words of textsplit
for idx, item in enumerate(textsplit):

    #If a word matches owl, append it's index to list
    if item.lower() == 'owl':
        indexlist.append(idx)

print(indexlist)
```

So output will look like

```
 enter some text i owl u u owl me
[1, 4]
```

The above code can be shortened by a lot if we use `list-comprehension` as follows. This code does the same thing as the for loop above, but is a more compact and shorter representation of it

```
text = input (' enter some text ' )

textsplit = text.split()

indexlist = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(textsplit) if item.lower() == 'owl']

print(indexlist)
```

Comment: How would you suggest handling duplicates?

Comment: This is great but is there a way to incorporate the enumerate function in this code? I think that by using enumerate, there wouldn't be the issue with duplicates

Comment: If you only have one `owl` in your string, you don't need enumerate, but if you have more than one `owl` enumerate will work! Let me add that part

Comment: Added that part @haf23 please check

Comment: Great thanks! @Devesh Kumar Singh Could you explain to me whats the point or meaning of " idx for idx "

Comment: That is the `list-comprehension` solution, do you know how that works @haf23 ? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions ?

Comment: And what exactly is the "if item.lower()" doing? Is lower a function to set all letters to lowercase? Thanks. Wait nevermind, I got it now. Thanks for you help

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not too familiar with llist comprehension

Comment: Yes, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower `lower()`  sets all letters to lowercase, so if the string is like `oWl`, it will convert it to `owl`. Also if you are not familiar, go through the link I posted to learn more, and you can ignore the last solution for now which uses list-comprehension, and check the middle solution which uses `enumerate` @haf23

Comment: @haf23 do you have any questions about the answer posted! let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of syntax errors here, as well as incorrectly applied variables. You won't really need `enumerate` for this either.
You could try this, using a list comprehension:

```
text = input('enter some text ').split()
indexlist = [i for i in range(len(text)) if text[i] == 'owl']
print(indexlist)
```

This will return the indexes of all occurrences in the input.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are powerful, if you can comprehend them

```
text = input (' enter some text ' )
print([i for i, t in enumerate(text.split()) if t.lower() == 'owl'])
```

If you test it...

```
You are an owl and i am an owl too
Out: [3, 8]
```